# How to route to 404 page when entered url is wrong on rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently in my rails app when somebody types wrong url it is made to give a flash `alert` as **Page not found** as follows.

**routes.rb**

`match '*path', to: redirect{ |p, req| req.flash[:alert] = "Page not found"; '/' }, via: :all`

Instead I want it to direct to the `404` page which is in **public/404.html**

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's better not to use 404 from public folder.

You can add at your routes:

`match "/404" => "errors#error404", via: [ :get, :post, :patch, :delete ]`

Than in application controller or even better to create ErrorsController, to add `render status: :not_found`

Also add your own view according to controller.

Comment: I added the first line in routes.rb. And created `def error404` in application controller and added `render status: :not_found` inside that. And when I entered localhost:3000/ssdsd. I got `no route mathces ssdsd.`

Comment: @user3576036 according to first line in routes, you need to add `def error404` in ErrorsController instead of ApplicationController, because "errors#error404" linking to it (take a look how routing in Rails works http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. No it didn't work. As you said I created another controller called **errors_controller.rb** and inside that I gave `def error404` method and added `match "/404" => "errors#error404", via: [ :get, :post, :patch, :delete ]` to **routes.rb** file. And set                               ` config.consider_all_requests_local = true` in **development.rb** . And when gave a random url it returned `No route matches [GET] "/cdsc"`

Comment: It worked when I set `config.consider_all_requests_local = false`. But I don't want it to set `false` because I like to see the `rails log errors` on the browser itself instead of a `something went wrong`

Comment: @user3576036 That's right.
So, don't use it for now on development. Test it and use on production only.

Answer (score 0):

If your message/content is not dynamic, I would recommend customizing your current `404.html` page instead (no need to add `match` to your routes, rails will redirect to `public/404.html` by default for any url not found in your routes).

If you do want a custom 404 page, then go with @TiSer answer.